# GoLang - why is logging to stdin valid?

Tags: go, logging

```
log.New(os.Stdin, "in", 1).Println("TT")
```

The following code out stream looks like it should use stdout or stderr, but I'm using the stdin input stream.
It should go into some panic, but output to the console normally.

Why is this working fine?
I don't know why.

um Isn't stream input used to type on the keyboard? But since I input stream input to output, I don't think this should work. stdout:console,
stderr:console,
stdin:keyboard

Comment: Please update the question title to something more specific - "Why is this working?" is not very descriptive of the question itself. I would suggest: "GoLang - why is logging to stdin valid?"

Comment: "Why is this working fine?" Why shouldn't it? Why do you think writing to a file should not work?

Comment: um sorry Isn't stream input used to type on the keyboard? But since I input stream input to output, I don't think this should work.        stdout:console, stderr:console, stdin:keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR - From the source code:

```golang
var (
    Stdin  = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdin), "/dev/stdin")
    Stdout = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stdout), "/dev/stdout")
    Stderr = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stderr), "/dev/stderr")
)
```

> Stdin, Stdout, and Stderr are open Files pointing to the standard
> input, standard output, and standard error file descriptors.

what this actually means is that Go treats Stdin, Stdout and Stderr the same, just as regular Files. and why shouldn't it? that's really just what they are. If you run `echo sometext > /dev/stdin` in your shell of choice, you'll see that this is valid and the text "sometext" will be printed to the terminal

### Digging Deeper

Let's examine the `log.New` function declaration:

```golang
func New(out io.Writer, prefix string, flag int) *Logger
```

> New creates a new Logger. The out variable sets the destination to
> which log data will be written. The prefix appears at the beginning of
> each generated log line, or after the log header if the Lmsgprefix
> flag is provided. The flag argument defines the logging properties.

You can see that the first argument is the `io.Writer` interface - which is declared as :

```golang
type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

This effectively means that `log.New` accepts every struct that has a `Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)` method. And because `os.Stdin` is of type [os.File](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File), it matches the `io.Writer` interface specification and the signature of `log.New`.